# show window preview on hover in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

Ubuntu 17.10 (Xorg), gnome 3.26.2.

When applications are minimized to the dock, is there a way to get a window preview of the applications when the pointer hovers over the icon in the dock?

I do not want this in place of the "All Windows" context menu item, I am interested in the preview in addition to the menu item.

(I see that the "Dash to panel" extension provides this option, but I do not want all the other features of that extension.)

Comment: Missing this feature from Windows since I migrated to Ubuntu.